# Are there any MSSQL Licencing restrictions regarding ArcGIS Server Services

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, license

I use ArcGIS Server in conjuction with MSSQL Server 2012.

According to my Database Administrator there could be licencing restrictions on the side of MSSQL when publishing Data over the web with ArcGIS Server when the source datasets are stored within MSSQL. It's all to do with mssql nodes.

Would anyone know if there are any such restrictions regarding data use from MSSQL Servers?

Comment: There should be logs showing that one user (either a user in your domain ... you? or one made for your ArcGIS Server installation) makes all the connections. I could be wrong, but that sounds like nonsense to me.

Comment: This is a question for a lawyer, not the Internet.

Comment: Heres a pdf guide to [SQL 2012 licencing](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/C/73CAD4E0-D0B5-4BE5-AB49-D5B886A5AE00/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf)

Comment: This is a licensing question for commercial software, which would be best asked of the software vendor, and is off-topic here.